Extract difference between slightly misaligned images with ImageMagick
I have 2 screenshots from a video game, of a person's gloves and a knife. The knife and the background are identical, while the gloves are different. I want to get the different part between the images, just the gloves, and make everything else transparent. So the output should just be the gloves, with a transparent knife-shaped hole in them.
The problem is that the images are ever so slightly misaligned (because they're from a video game). So everything I've tried so far hasn't turned out correctly, but the images are still similar enough that I feel like it should be possible to do this.
This is yellowgloves.png

And this is pinkgloves.png

Here's what I tried using IM's ChangeMask method: magick yellowgloves.png pinkgloves.png -fuzz 5% -compose ChangeMask -composite output.png
And here's the output.png:

This was the best I could get from adjusting the fuzz factor, and it's somewhat close to what I want. I haven't found any good way to de-noise this output image either, but that could work too.
How would you recommend I do this, if it's possible?

ok so align them? can't imagemagick do that? if it can't (I don't know), you'd need to find something that can.

well, that's the thing, i don't know how to align them. they're not just slightly offset on one axis, it's both axes, and because of that one of images (whichever one is lower) actually just doesn't have the same number of pixels in the shape as the other. and i have a lot more images to perform this task on, all of which will have other different minor offsets, so i can't just guess and check to align them.
unless imagemagick does have that functionality, which i haven't heard of (i'm pretty new though i suppose)

since they're reasonably well aligned already, just apply all the usual methods to remove small debris. lowpass (smooth), or morphology operations, or a lot of other things. even with alignment, you'd have to do that anyway.

yeah, you were right, it just took a bunch of median and morphology combos and it came out pretty good, thanks
